# Getting Mutating error while running trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger, mutating-table

I am getting table is mutating error  when I try to update the table

```
update flight 
set captainStaffID='S0009' 
where flightid='000000043';
```

Here is the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger trigger1 
before INSERT OR UPDATE of captainStaffID,firstOfficerStaffID on flight
for each row


if UPDATING  then
    select count(*) into temp7 
    from flight 
    where flightid in (select ap.flightid  
                       from ADDITIONAL_PILOT ap 
                       where activityCode ='TR');
    dbms_output.put_line('New'||:new.flightid||'OLD'||:old.flightid);


end if;

end trigger1;
/
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-04091: table XXXXXx.FLIGHT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
>   ORA-06512: at "XXXXXX.TRIGGER1", line 7
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger .....TRIGGER1'

I am using below update query to initiate my trigger

```
update flight set captainStaffID='S0009' where flightid='000000043';
```

Comment: What if the trigger executes after rather than before?

Comment: actually before an update is made to a row , i want to check if the entered values adhere to a business logic and hence i have made before update

Comment: To me it appears that you are doing a count and then printing something.

Comment: yes your are correct Joakim .I am doing that here since i am trying to learn triggers but yes intention is this piece of code to work before an update is made so that i can post learning this issue  incorporate the actual logic

Comment: Then what can we help you with? If you’re learning shouldn’t you study the error message and modify the trigger, to me it makes perfect sense that using count before doing an insert isn’t allowed even if I haven’t looked it up and verified it myself.

Comment: actually i am making an update to a row in a table but before the update is made/commited , i want to count some rows in a table based on a condition

Comment: Yes I can see that but the trigger is defined for insert and update

Comment: Mutating table is a well-established error in Oracle. Code in a trigger cannot execute DML (including SELECT) against the table which owns the trigger (to maintain transactional integrity). There are [already plenty of questions with solutions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+mutating%2Btable). Why not have a look at some of them?

Comment: hi APC, Many thanks for your reply. I know have better understanding of this concept . thank you

Comment: You're welcome. If you are still stuck implementing a solution by all means update this question with more details.